# Why I can't use different log levels in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I want to use different log levels. For example I need to log actions as INFO if everyting is OK, and WARNING when the required action is NOT proceeded OK (or ERROR, FATAl etc. it doesn't matter right now). How can I reach it? Basically I need just 2 levels, but unfortunately if I am trying to use 2 levels then my log file created as empty. Below is my code but it doesn't work and log file created empty.

```
class Logger:
@staticmethod
def info_logger(logLevel=log.INFO):
    logger_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    logger = log.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logLevel)
    fh = log.FileHandler(log_file)
    formatter = log.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I: %M: %S %p')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger

@staticmethod
def warning_logger(logLevel=log.WARNING):
    logger_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    logger = log.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logLevel)
    fh = log.FileHandler(error_log_file)
    formatter = log.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I: %M: %S %p')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where is the code which makes calls to log messages? The posted code only returns a logger.

Comment: What is `log`? Is it an alias for the `logging` module?

Comment: also, why not just create a single logger? You are duplicating code. Do a conditional in your function to check `logLevel` value and change the logfile based on that

Comment: are you writing any logs? The log files will be empty until you create a log. (No logs are created in the code in your post.)